# Azure Mobile Service getting error - Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have simple `Azure Mobile Service` which is connected to `MySql Database`

`Web.Config`

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Server=11.11.111.111;User Id=test;Password=test;Database=testDB" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

`App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {           
            ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();

            HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));

             config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        }
    }
```

`Controllers\CommentController.cs`

```
 public class CommentController : TableController<wp_comments>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<wp_comments>(context, Request, Services);
        }

        // GET tables/Comment
        public IQueryable<wp_comments> GetAllComment()
        {               
            return Query(); // Getting Exception Here
        }
```

`DataObjects\wp_comments.cs`

```
public class wp_comments : EntityData
    {
        public int comment_ID { get; set; }
        public int comment_post_ID { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_author", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_author { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_author_email", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_author_email { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_author_url", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_author_url { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_author_IP", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_author_IP { get; set; }
        public DateTime comment_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime comment_date_gmt { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_author_IP", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_content { get; set; }
        public int comment_karma { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_approved", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_approved { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_agent", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_agent { get; set; }

        [Column("comment_type", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
        public string comment_type { get; set; }
        public int comment_parent { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
    }
```

`Models\MobileServiceContext.cs`

```
public class MobileServiceContext : DbContext
    {

        private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

        public MobileServiceContext() : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<wp_comments> Comments { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            string schema = ServiceSettingsDictionary.GetSchemaName();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema))
            {
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema);
            }

            //modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
            //    new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
            //        "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with your model, you have defined the same property "comment_author_IP". Please modify it then to see whether your code works.

```
    [Column("comment_author_IP", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string comment_author_IP { get; set; }
    public DateTime comment_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime comment_date_gmt { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_author_IP", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string comment_content { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks i corrected that still same error - 
then I again removed all `[Column]` attributes and it works :)